# Custom many to one manager on self

Tags: django, python-3.x, model

I'm trying to use a custom Manager on my model but would like it to also be used in the self relationship so I can add some code to the add method. Here's the code:

```
from django.db import models

class TestModelManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def __init__(self):
        models.Manager.__init__(self)

    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('My custom code.')
        super().add(*args, **kwargs)

class TestModel(models.Model):

    objects = TestModelManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='children',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Python shell output

```
>>> from testmods.models import TestModel
>>> TestModel.objects
<testmods.models.TestModelManager object at 0x10bc96e80>
>>> TestModel.objects.bulk_create([TestModel(name="foo"), TestModel(name="bar")])
[<TestModel: TestModel object>, <TestModel: TestModel object>]
>>> t1, t2 = TestModel.objects.all()
>>> t1.children.add(t2)
>>> t1.children.all()
<QuerySet [<TestModel: TestModel object>]>
>>>
```

In the line `t1.children.add(t2)` why didn't it print "My custom code."?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer perusing then source code. It appears that the add method is added to the custom manager and cannot be modified in the method described above.

```
def create_reverse_many_to_one_manager(superclass, rel):
    """
    Create a manager for the reverse side of a many-to-one relation.
    This manager subclasses another manager, generally the default manager of
    the related model, and adds behaviors specific to many-to-one relations.
    """
```